# Chrome tries to load video formats it does not support, failing to load those it does

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video

When I load videos in the order .mov and then .webm:

```
<video controls width="500" height="200">
    <source src="some-video.mov" mime="video/quicktime">
    <source src="some-video.webm" mime="video/webm">
</video>
```

Chrome is trying to load the .mov file, even though it doesn't support it, rather than using the .webm version that it does support. All other modern browsers I've tested are acting as expected: Safari loads .mov since it supports it, while all other browsers skip .mov and load .webm instead.

Here's a codepen with demos of this issue: https://codepen.io/tcmulder/full/XWqZYmx

(For those of you who need to know *why* I want to load a .mov in Safari at all: I'm trying to have a video with a transparent background on a site; all browsers except Safari support transparency in .webm, while Safari only supports transparency for .mov videos.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** Your Webm loads fine in Chrome for Windows (it auto-skips the MOV file)

**(2)** Try using **type** instead of **mime**:

```
<video controls width="500" height="200">
    <source src="some-video.mov" type="video/quicktime">
    <source src="some-video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```